# Calculation inside a data frame based on two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

Say, I have a data frame with 3 columns

```
ID     Type      Amount
1      4         100
1      4         50
1      1         20
2      4         30
2      1         10
```

I want to do some calculations in the data frame which are based on the groups of ID and Type. For example, I want to calculate the sum of amount **for type 4** - sum of amount **for type 1** for all of the IDs of the data frame and append it to the end, so the final result would be something like

```
ID     Type      Amount    Calculation
1      4         100       (100 + 50) - 20
1      4         50        (100 + 50) - 20
1      1         20        (100 + 50) - 20
2      4         30        30 - 10
2      1         10        30 - 10
```

Is there an easy way to implement this? Easy, because I want to do some more complexe calculations, but want to get the basics right first.

I tried to work it out with `dplyr`

Something like

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 sum( Calculation = Amount[Type == 4] - Amount[Type == 1])
```

This gave me the same value for all the columns in my data frame, so it doesn't seem to work.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you need with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2), Type = c(4,4,1,4,1), Amount = c(100,50,20,30,10))

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Calculation = sum(Amount[Type == 4]) - sum(Amount[Type == 1]))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID  Type Amount Calculation
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1     4    100         130
2     1     4     50         130
3     1     1     20         130
4     2     4     30          20
5     2     1     10          20
```